# How to analyze numerical error of matrix-vector product caused by fluctuations on matrix elements

Tags: c++, matrix, numerical-analysis

I am seeking a way to quantify the error of matrix-vector multiplication caused by numerical error of matrix elements. In my recent project, I implemented a routine that generates a translation matrix.

```
// p decides the size of the truncated matrix (truncation number)
void genHorizCoaxMat(const double wavNum, const double t, const double* a_coeffs, const double* b_coeffs, const int p, cuDoubleComplex* mat)
```

I used the following routine to test the stability of matrix generation:

```
void testGenCoaxStability()
{
    double t = 0.02;
    double delta_t = 1.0e-16; // fluctuation
    int p = 10; // truncation number
    double freq = 5000, wavNum = 2*PI*freq/SOUND_SPEED; // frequency and wavenumber
    double *a_coeffs = (double*)malloc(TRANSVECSZ(ENLP(p))*sizeof(double)); // auxiliary numbers
    double *b_coeffs = (double*)malloc(TRANSVECSZ(ENLP(p))*sizeof(double)); // auxiliary numbers
    
    // generate auxiliary coefficients
    for(int n = 0; n < ENLP(p); n++)
    {
        for(int m = -n; m <= n; m++)
        {
            a_coeffs[NM2IDX0(n,m)] = aCoeff(n,m);
            b_coeffs[NM2IDX0(n,m)] = bCoeff(n,m);
        }
    }
    cuDoubleComplex *mat1 = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(COAXMATSZ(p)*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    cuDoubleComplex *mat2 = (cuDoubleComplex*)malloc(COAXMATSZ(p)*sizeof(cuDoubleComplex));
    
    genHorizCoaxMat(wavNum,t,a_coeffs,b_coeffs,p,mat1); // generate matrix with no fluctuation
    genHorizCoaxMat(wavNum,t+delta_t,a_coeffs,b_coeffs,p,mat2); // with fluctuation
    free(a_coeffs);
    free(b_coeffs);
    subArr(mat1,mat2,COAXMATSZ(p)); // subtract two arrays for comparison
    printf("Numerical error induced by a fluctuation on t:\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < COAXMATSZ(p); i++)
    {
        printf("(%lf,%lf) ",cuCreal(mat1[i]),cuCimag(mat1[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(mat1);
    free(mat2);
}
```

As I found out from its print, a tiny fluctuation on argument 't' leads to non-negligible error on certain elements when 't' is small and 'p' is large:

```
Numerical error induced by a fluctuation on t:
(0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000035) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000035) (0.000000,0.000525) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000035) (0.000000,-0.000523) (-0.000000,0.008514) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000002) (0.000000,-0.000035) (0.000000,0.000522) (-0.000000,-0.008499) (0.000000,0.147949) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000034) (-0.000000,-0.000522) (0.000000,0.008499) (0.000000,-0.147705) (-0.000000,2.710938) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000035) (-0.000000,0.000523) (-0.000000,-0.008499) (-0.000000,0.147705) (0.000000,-2.707031) (0.000000,53.250000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000035) (-0.000000,-0.000525) (-0.000000,0.008514) (-0.000000,-0.147949) (-0.000000,2.707031) (-0.000000,-53.250000) (0.000000,1104.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000029) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000029) (0.000000,-0.000444) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000030) (0.000000,0.000449) (-0.000000,-0.007401) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000002) (0.000000,0.000030) (0.000000,-0.000451) (-0.000000,0.007446) (0.000000,-0.129639) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000030) (-0.000000,0.000451) (0.000000,-0.007462) (0.000000,0.130127) (-0.000000,-2.414062) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000029) (-0.000000,-0.000449) (-0.000000,0.007446) (0.000000,-0.130127) (0.000000,2.417969) (0.000000,-47.875000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000029) (-0.000000,0.000444) (-0.000000,-0.007416) (-0.000000,0.129883) (-0.000000,-2.414062) (-0.000000,47.875000) (0.000000,-1000.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000001) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000001) (-0.000000,0.000016) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000001) (-0.000000,-0.000017) (0.000000,0.000270) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000001) (-0.000000,0.000018) (0.000000,-0.000286) (-0.000000,0.004791) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000001) (0.000000,-0.000019) (0.000000,0.000293) (-0.000000,-0.004936) (0.000000,0.088135) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000001) (-0.000000,0.000018) (-0.000000,-0.000293) (0.000000,0.004982) (0.000000,-0.089600) (-0.000000,1.683594) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000001) (-0.000000,-0.000017) (-0.000000,0.000286) (-0.000000,-0.004936) (-0.000000,0.089600) (0.000000,-1.691406) (0.000000,34.187500) (0.000000,-0.000001) (-0.000000,0.000016) (-0.000000,-0.000270) (-0.000000,0.004776) (-0.000000,-0.088135) (-0.000000,1.683594) (-0.000000,-34.187500) (0.000000,725.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000005) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000007) (0.000000,-0.000111) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000001) (-0.000000,-0.000008) (0.000000,0.000130) (-0.000000,-0.002247) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000001) (0.000000,0.000008) (0.000000,-0.000139) (-0.000000,0.002441) (0.000000,-0.045044) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000008) (-0.000000,0.000139) (0.000000,-0.002502) (0.000000,0.046875) (-0.000000,-0.916016) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000007) (-0.000000,-0.000130) (-0.000000,0.002441) (-0.000000,-0.046875) (0.000000,0.931641) (0.000000,-19.343750) (0.000000,-0.000005) (0.000000,0.000111) (-0.000000,-0.002251) (-0.000000,0.044922) (-0.000000,-0.916016) (-0.000000,19.343750) (0.000000,-426.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000002) (0.000000,0.000027) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000002) (0.000000,-0.000040) (-0.000000,0.000729) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000003) (0.000000,0.000046) (-0.000000,-0.000872) (0.000000,0.016876) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000002) (-0.000000,-0.000046) (0.000000,0.000919) (0.000000,-0.018402) (-0.000000,0.376953) (-0.000000,-0.000002) (-0.000000,0.000040) (-0.000000,-0.000872) (-0.000000,0.018402) (0.000000,-0.390625) (0.000000,8.531250) (0.000000,-0.000027) (-0.000000,0.000727) (-0.000000,-0.016876) (-0.000000,0.378906) (-0.000000,-8.531250) (0.000000,196.250000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000007) (-0.000000,-0.000139) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000000) (0.000000,-0.000010) (-0.000000,0.000208) (0.000000,-0.004333) (-0.000000,-0.000000) (-0.000000,0.000010) (0.000000,-0.000232) (0.000000,0.005135) (-0.000000,-0.112793) (-0.000000,-0.000007) (-0.000000,0.000208) (-0.000000,-0.005135) (0.000000,0.120117) (0.000000,-2.843750) (-0.000000,-0.000139) (-0.000000,0.004326) (-0.000000,-0.113037) (-0.000000,2.843750) (0.000000,-70.375000) (0.000000,-0.000000) (0.000000,0.000001) (-0.000000,-0.000028) (0.000000,0.000655) (-0.000000,-0.000001) (0.000000,0.000036) (0.000000,-0.000946) (-0.000000,0.023071) (-0.000000,-0.000028) (-0.000000,0.000946) (0.000000,-0.026001) (0.000000,0.686523) (-0.000000,-0.000655) (-0.000000,0.023071) (-0.000000,-0.686523) (0.000000,18.937500) (0.000000,-0.000003) (0.000000,0.000093) (-0.000000,-0.002705) (-0.000000,-0.000093) (0.000000,0.003510) (0.000000,-0.109375) (-0.000000,-0.002708) (-0.000000,0.109375) (0.000000,-3.578125) (0.000000,-0.000222) (0.000000,0.009476) (-0.000000,-0.009476) (0.000000,0.424805) (0.000000,-0.023834)
```

As I analyzed, the instability is from spherical Bessel functions of the second kind y_n(x) when n >> x. As the purpose of generating this matrix is to conduct matrix-vector multiplication, I would like to analyze theoretically if these numerical errors leads to large errors in the product. My problem should be formalized as, for a given vector x, define a function f(T) = Tx, where T is a matrix, how to describe the influence of fluctuation Delta_T on the function f?

Comment: What is the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of this matrix?

Comment: To follow up on Evg, if the condition number of your matrix is high, you may have large errors. If the condition number is low, you won't have large errors.

Comment: @Evg@TohpiMou At first I thought condition number is defined for the stability of Ax = b on b. Then I realized that the condition number for f(x) = Ax on x is the same as that of Ax = b on b. However, my problem is to study the stability of f(A) = Ax on A, as A is the source of fluctuation. Seems to be a different problem.